# How do I install Microsoft Exchange 2013 with Microsoft Powershell DSC?

Tags: exchange, powershell, windows-server-2012, exchange-2013, dsc

We are working on a new build procedure. As a proof of concept, I wanted to install an Exchange 2013 server with CAS and Hub roles.

I cannot find documentation on just how to do that. Has anyone tried this? I've seen examples for Windows Server roles but not for product specific roles (e..g, Exchange).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a custom DSC resource which installs Exchange (or perhaps it'd be better to create more than one, in order to separate the Exchange AD prerequisites from the actual Exchange installation).

For installing Exchange from Powershell I did a quick search and found a resource (which I haven't tried) with the title [Howto Install Exchange 2013 Using Powershell on Windows Server 2012](http://techdom.nl/microsoft/howto-install-exchange-2013-powershell-windows-server-2012/).

When it comes to creating a custom DSC resource, you could look into [the Technet library page for creating a custom DSC resource](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249927.aspx).

Do be aware that they seem to have changed the location for DSC resources. At least on my Win8.1 machine on which I just tried making one I found it to be C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration\DSCResources (DSCResources instead of PSProviders as last subfolder). The PSProviders folder seems to be stated at most places found online (including Microsoft's documentation), so perhaps that's the folder on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine. I can't comment on that since I don't have any such machine to try it on at the moment. On my Win 8.1 machine, however, it was DSCResources, not PSProviders, so either it's an old location which is still stated in documentation or it's different on different OS versions.

Comment: I would have liked to include a link to [an article on a Custom Desired State Configuration (DSC) Resource for System Center](http://www.systemcentercentral.com/custom-desired-state-configuration-dsc-resource-for-system-center/), but my 'reputation' on serverfault is too low to include three links in an answer so I included it here instead.

Comment: :) Well you gave a good answer anyway, and I upvoted it which should help you get past that problem next time.